# No solutions found in MT StrategyTester optimization mode when using INIT_FAILED or INIT_PARAMTERS_INCORRECT

Tags: mql4, metatrader4, mql5, metatrader5

I'm trying to optimize my current EA that contains approximately 40 different inputs with MetaTrader genetic algorithm.

The inputs have constraints such as I1 < I2 < I3, I24 > 0, ... For total of about 20 constraints.

I tried to filter the solutions that do not respect the constraints with the following code :

```
int OnInit(){
   if(I1 >= I2 || I2 >= I3) {
      return(INIT_FAILED);
   }
   ...
}
```

The problem is then the following : no viable solutions are found after the first 512 iterations and the optimization stops (same happens with the non genetic optimizer).

If I remove the constraints the algorithm will run and optimize the solutions but then those solutions will not respect the constraints.

Has anyone already faced similar issues ? Currently I think I'll have to use an external tool to optimize but this does not feel right

Comment: It happens sometimes that you cannot find a suitable set after optimization  -all sets bring loss. And you cannot fix that unless changing the logic. You may try to disable genetic algorithm in optimization inputs, that will take more time to run the tests and probably with the same result

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel has yesterday recommended an `OnInit(){...}`-handler located shortcutting, **the Genetic-mode optimiser** will and **has to give-up**, as it has not seen any progression on the evolutionary journey across some recent amount of population modifications/mutations down the road.

What has surprised me, is that the fully-meshed mode ( going across the whole Cartesian parameterSetSPACE ) rejected to test each and every parameterSetSPACE-vector, one after another. Having spent remarkable hundreds of machine-years in this very sort of testing, this sounds strange to my prior MT4 [ Strategy Tester ] experience.

---

### One more trick :

Let me share one more option :

let pass the tested code through the `OnInit(){...}`, but make the conditions shortcut the `OnTick(){...}`-event-handler, returning straight upon entering there. This was a trick, we have invented so as our code was able to simulate some delayed starts ( an internal time-based iterator, for a sliding window location in a flow of time ) of the actual trading-under-test. This way one may simulate some adverse effect of "wrong" parameterSet-vectors, and the Genetics may evolve further, even finding as a side-effect what types of parametrisation gets penalised :o)

---

### SearchSpace having 40+ parameters ?    ... The Performance !

If this is your concerd, your next level of performance gets delivered, once you start using a [distributed-computing](/questions/tagged/distributed-computing) testing-farm, where many machines perform tests upon centrally managed distribution of `parameterSet`-vectors and report back the results.

This was indeed a performance booster for our Quant R&D.

After some time, we have also implemented a "standalone" farm for ( again, [distributed-computing](/questions/tagged/distributed-computing) ) off-platform Quant R&D prototyping and testing.